# Можно ли применять условия внутри append при добавлении html?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я добавляю в блок свой html код, делаю это так:

```
$('#block').append(`
     ... my new html insert ....
`);
```

Можно ли внутри **append** применять условия? (как?)
Например я бы хотел сделать так:

```
$('#block').append(`
     ... my new html insert ....
     if (test == 1) {
         ... test html insert ...
     }
`);
```

Comment: Только тернарный условный оператор: `?:`

Comment: @smellyshovel можно пример пожалуйста?

Comment: `.append(ё${ test == 1 ? "One string" : "Another string"}ё)` - только вместо букв ё используйте кавычки как у вас в вопросе. Это я просто так сделал из-за проблем с экранированием (они используются для обозначения блока кода здесь на сайте).

Comment: Только учтите, что это сделает ваш код намного менее читаемым и сложнее воспринимаемым. Лучше такого избегать. Если есть возможность, вынесите `if` наружу и просто сделайте 2 `append`а.

Comment: @smellyshovel спасибо! спаботало!